# networking issue about virtual machine as gateway on vSphere esxi

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, linux-networking, vmware-vsphere, gateway

I have configured ESXi environment as below. plus i use ESXi with vCenter 6.7. And the type of virtual switches is standard virtual switch.

**Baremetal host - vSwitch0(uplink-ESXi nic0) - Gateway VM - vSwitch1 - Guest OS**

I want to connect baremetal host to Guest OS via Gateway VM. But that is not working. First, Gateway can ping baremetal host and internal guest OS on vSwitch1.

So I had created new temporary vSwitch for test to gateway VM routing. As result, internal networking is perfectly ok. Plus i had configured NAT on Gateway VM and The internal VM can ping baremetal host but vice versa is not working.

In my opinion, ESXi uplink block this traffic...

What's problem in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You want to connect from the ESXi console to another system.
Do you have opened the firewall on the host for this connections?

Look in "Configuration -> Security Profile" if your connection is opened. e.G. SSH Client is normally blocked.

Additionally you must have a static route on your ESXi host for the guest OS network if the gateway VM is not your default.

ESXi vmkernel: 192.168.1.10/24
ESXi default gateway: 192.168.1.1
Gateway VM: 192.168.1.2
Guest OS: 192.168.2.10/24

Route on ESXi: esxcfg-route -a 192.168.2.0/24 192.168.1.2